# need the equivalent of a left-aligned <hr> in html email

Tags: html-email

HTML email newbie here. Cannot **believe** how hard a simple thing can be in this arena...

I need a left-aligned, 1 pixel high, 350 pixels wide, colored line that I can put between lines of text in an HTML email.

Something like `<hr align="left" style="height: 1px; width: 350px; color: #ff0000;" />` but of course that doesn't work in various versions of Outlook (I need to support 2003+) and Entourage (I need to support 2004+). (Other clients aren't giving me the same sort of grief, of course.)

Actual `<hr>`s are apparently untweakable in Entourage, so I've tried all sorts of things, including 1px high `<p>`s with a background color. Everything I try breaks somewhere.

Anyone have a bulletproof way to produce this simple line w/o resorting to an image?

Comment: You've got to do it in tables. There's a great resource here about what you can and can't to in HTML emails -> http://www.emailology.org/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around not using an image for this.

What you need to do is add a spacer image and a background color.

Im not sure how you have your email laid out, but if this was for me i would do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZsCwX/

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
  <tr>
    <td height="1px" width="350px" style="background-color:#F00;"><img src="image/spacer.gif" alt="" width="350" height="1" style="display:block" border="0" /></td>
    <td height="1px" width="250px"><img src="image/spacer.gif" alt="" width="250" height="1" style="display:block" border="0" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>​
```

Comment: No need for the spacer images - they can actually be harmful, as they increase the spam score and some clients can have problems with them. Also, the `height` and `width` HTML attributes do **not** have `px` after them. You only use a unit if it's `%`.

Comment: There is lots of need for spacer images! Especially for cross client comparability in Outlook 2007 + 2010.

Comment: Have you tested that? I've built 100s of emails that worked fine in all major email clients (inc Outlook 2007 + 2010) without spacer gifs. I just wrote a Q+A on this so we can debate outside comments - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732164/do-i-need-to-use-spacer-images-when-coding-html-emails

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<tr>
        <td style="padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:30px;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="350">
                <tbody>
                    <td align="left" bgcolor="#ff0000" style="font-size: 1px; line-height:1px; color:#ff0000">&zwnj;</td>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
</tr>
```